# How to find fitting parameters of the function?

Tags: optimization, parameter-estimation

I have the function describing the experimental data - $f(x)$. I also have another function - $g(x, \bar{p})$, which is the theoretical function for the process involved. Here $\bar{p}$ - is the vector of additional unknown parameters of model description. I need to find vector $\bar{p}$, which is the best fitting parameters for $f(x)$ function.

I have tried the following solution. Lets introduce distance function of $f$ and $g$:

$$M(f, g) = M(\bar{p}) = \sqrt{\int_{0}^{1} (f(x) - g(x, \bar{p}))^2 dx}$$

Here interval $[0,1]$ is the interested. And by minimizing the $M(\bar{p})$ I get what I want - vector $\bar{p}$. Disadvantage of this method is that it finds only one solution, probably not the best one. I use [Rsolnp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rsolnp/index.html) package to search the minimum, which implements `General Non-linear Optimization Using Augmented Lagrange Multiplier Method`.

It works well, it finds the resulting vector.

Is there any other methods or algorithms for this task? What advantages they offer?

Comment: You can get rid of the square root, it doesn't change the minimum's position. And there is no sure-fire way to get the global minimum, the only suggestion is to try to estimate the parameters somehow beforehand to limit the search, or try different starting points for the optimizer.

Comment: I have used the limits for parameters in search operation. Now I will try to change starting point.

Comment: You could do worse than to start by checking the Wikipedia page for [nonlinear least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares), which is basically what you are doing. The [Gauss-Newton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm) and [Levenberg-Marquardt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) algorithms are popular numerical methods for such problems.